# Matlab Coloring a rectangle by range of input data

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a measured pressure data whose values vary from 0 to 300 psig.  I'd like to draw a rectangle by rectangle, patch, polyshape, etc. and vary its color in proportion to the pressure data so that I can create an animation that visualizes the pressure change over time.

The trouble I'm having is to correlate a pressure value to `FaceColor` (or similar parameters).  I can divide the pressure data into sections (greater than or less than type of logic) and specify `red`, `green`, `yellow`, `blue`, etc. to different sections, but I'd like to show a color gradient rather than discrete colors when playing the animation.

Comment: You need to have your rectangle divided into a **grid**, and calculate or interpolate the pressure values for each grid element. Obviously if you want to show an evolution in time you'll have to recalculate your pressure for each time step. The finer the color gradient the finer you should define your grid. Once you have all that (grid+pressure data), for the graphing functions I would look at `pcolor`, `contour`, `surf` or `patch`. Look at them in the documentation and decide which suits you most (the input format will be different depending on your choice).

Comment: @Hoki, please, make your commend as an answer so that I can select it.  I used path with interpl1 for grid-generation.  Thank you.

Comment: I only gave a overall methodology, there are dozens of way of implementing it depending on the specifics of your problem. You have to try something and post the code, we'll be able to help you if you're stuck, but we can't write something from scratch without knowing all your problem constraints ...

Answer (score 0):

The keyword that you're looking for is [colormap](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html#buq1hym).  This will allow you to map from your scalar value (pressure) to a color and even to add the corresponding colorbar.